# Incorrect synonym: ibm-i maps to ibm-midrange, should be other way around

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request, tag-synonyms

The **IBM i** platform has undergone a number of renames over the years from the original **AS/400** (which should in my opinion have been reinstated as it is the best search engine term, but I digress).

The current official title of the platform is **IBM i** (see header for page reached from http://ibm.com/as400) so the current synonym mapping at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ibm-midrange/synonyms is incorrect.

Could I ask a person with more rep than me to set either **as400** or **ibm-i** as the official synonym instead of *ibm-midrange*?